# Diferenças entre utilização de Cache e CDN

Tags: http, servidor, cache, otimização, cdn

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens ao utilizar CDN  (Content Delivery Network) e Cache e como eles podem se complementar?

Comment: Que tipo de cache está falando?

Comment: @bigown seria um servidor de cache de conteúdo. Estou pensando em um caso onde uma empresa precisa fornecer conteudo (ex. Netflix) e quais seriam as vantagens da utilização de cache ou cdn e como eles podem se complementar. Posso colocar isso na pergunta se for necessário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imaginando que o servidor de cache mencionado faça o mesmo que um CDN, a diferença principal é a distribuição do conteúdo. No CDN ele pode ser entregue por um servidor mais próximo do requisitante, o que diminui a latência e portanto a experiência do usuário melhora.

Em alguns casos o conteúdo pode ser universal e "todos" os sites usarem o mesmo URL para pegar, o que ajuda ficar no cache do navegador, então pode ser que nem tenha que carregar o jQuery (ou Angular ou Blazor) que seu site usa porque ele já está no navegador do usuário. Isto só é possível se você não usar um arquivo jQuery personalizado ou hospedado por você.

Essas empresas são especializadas nisso, sabem montar bem a infraestrutura, lidar com ataques diversos, você só tem que configurar para colocar o conteúdo lá. Ele costuma ser altamente disponível.

Em compensação ele tende custar mais caro em vários casos.

O CDN dispõe de diversos mecanismos para ajudar na melhor performance. Nem sempre o cache é o mecanismo mais adequado.

Uma das vantagens disso é que pode lidar com *streaming* de vídeo melhor que um cache que só funciona bem com pequenos objetos. Inclusive ele pode usar *multicasting* que pode reduzir bastante o consumo de banda e acabar fazendo o custo ficar mais baixo. Conteúdo ao vivo se beneficia do CDN por isto.

Conteúdo que se altera com certa frequência pode ser melhor entregue pelo cache. Mas nada impede dessa alteração se refletir no cache do CDN para obter outras vantagens. A função do seu próprio cache é melhor aproveitada para este tipo de conteúdo.

Não é garantido que o CDN entregará melhor em todos os casos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).