# Mascarar valor no input

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte, o usuario digita 1, no input teria o valor **,01**, ai ele digita 2, apareceria **,12**, ai ele digita 3, apareceria **1,23**, assim por diante. Tenho o input da seguinte maneira:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  id ="produto_preco_unitario" name="produto_preco_unitario"
                         value="" placeholder="Preço por Unidade" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mask = {
 money: function() {
    var el = this
    ,exec = function(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    v = new String(Number(v));
    var len = v.length;
    if (1== len)
    v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0.0$1");
    else if (2 == len)
    v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0.$1");
    else if (len > 2) {
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/,'.$1');
    }
    return v;
    };

    setTimeout(function(){
    el.value = exec(el.value);
    },1);
 }

}

$(function(){
 $('input').bind('keypress',mask.money)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  id ="produto_preco_unitario" name="produto_preco_unitario"
                     value="" placeholder="Preço por Unidade" required/>
```

**Você também pode usar com separador de milhar**

```js
$(function () { //ready
    $("#produto_preco_unitario").maskMoney();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
    
<input type="text" id="produto_preco_unitario" value="" />
```

O arquivo pega no github [jquery.maskMoney.js](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/blob/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.js)

Se quiser trocar a moeda para o formato português (decimal virgula e separador de milhar ponto) faça assim:

```js
$(function () { //ready
    $("#produto_preco_unitario").maskMoney({thousands: ".", decimal: ","});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
    
<input type="text" id="produto_preco_unitario" value="" />
```

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, na minha biblioteca do jquery.maskMoney.js eu já havia alterado para funcionar com formato de moeda (decimal virgula e separador de milhar ponto. Algum problema utilizar a biblioteca do meu site?

Comment: Só uma dica, esse plugin permite configurar o decimal sem precisar alterar o fonte. Basta ajustar os settings. Mexer no fonte para alterar uma coisa que tem configuração não é o melhor dos usos do plugin (apesar de funcionar alterando o fonte, é algo a mais pra se ficar mantendo versão paralela, e no caso, desnecessariamente). Fica a sugestão de atualizar a resposta para valorizar.

Comment: Já que não há problema algum porque mudar? Não, não sei o que é CDN, quando tiver interesse vou procurar saber algo a respeito.

Comment: CDN é Content Delivery Network, um jeito de distribuir arquivos por vários servidores e aproveitar o mesmo endereço, de forma a agilizar o acesso, e ao mesmo tempo reaproveitar o cache do cliente. Usando o oficial, você tem muito mais chance do recurso não sair do ar, além da maior performance (mas no caso, não suportaria alterações de sua parte, tem os 2 lados da moeda, além da questão de privacidade do usuário final)

Comment: Espero que realmente você saiba o que é *open-source* e o que é apoiar um projeto *open-source*, portanto recomendo padronizar conforme o "versionamento" da lib no repositório para que se haja algum BUG que eles venham a corrigir no CDN será atualizado, e realmente não há necessidade de adicionar uma configuração "internas" sendo que a propria lib fornece isso conforme o link que lhe enviei.

Comment: Sobre CDN, aqui tem alguns conceitos [O que é CDN e como habilitá-lo nos meus arquivos JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168575/70) - [Diferenças entre utilização de Cache e CDN](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189323/70) - [Criando um CDN - content delivery network](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119766/70)

Comment: Entendi, então faz isso lá na minha resposta para que ao clicar em executar fique da forma que eu tinha feito.

Comment: Pra resumir isto resolve `$("#produto_preco_unitario").maskMoney({thousands: ".", decimal: ","});`, veja como é simples, não gastou mais que uma linha e não precisa ficar modificando o arquivo original que é mantido por open-source por muitas pessoas que deram o trabalho para criar um sistema de configuração e assim acompanhar o versionamento de maneira correta ;), espero que entenda como critica construtiva.

Comment: Sim entendi, faça isso lá na minha resposta e ficarei imensamente grato!

Comment: Deixa eu te falar uma coisa. Fiquei a noite toda acordado para descobrir porque só na minha maquina não abria muitos sites. Nas maquinas da rede todos funcionavam, inclusive celulares com wifi. Nem o adsense abria nos meus sites aqui na minha maquina, sites do Google nenhum. Não consegui resolver de jeito nenhum, e testei varias soluções, inclusive da indicada pelo site do SO. Tive que reinstalar o SO. Moral da história: O melhor é não depender de nada de terceiros, vai que .....

Comment: Eu concordo, mas tecnicamente o seu site seria de terceiros ali, não concorda? Se um Adblock bloquear um cdn, como maxcdn, então 50% dos sites da internet parariam de funcionar.