# Usar CDN ou arquivos armazenados localmente?

Tags: cdn

Sei o que é um CDN, mas queria saber algumas outras coisas a respeito:

- Deveria optar por utilizar o CDN ou usar os arquivos armazenados localmente?
- Quais são as vantagens de usar cada uma das opções?
- Qual o cliente se beneficia mais?

**Não quero opinião, ou como faz e deixa de fazer**. Quero saber quais são as vantagens (com dados que comprovem a mesma) relacionado à velocidade de carregamento, e distribuição, assim como levar em conta a praticidade de manutenção e reparo da opção.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168575/101

Comment: Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189323/101